# How to remove OneDrive permanently

Tags: onedrive

I have Windows 10 with Office installed. I have uninstalled OneDrive after windows setup but it keeps installed with the updates. Is there a way to remove it once for all?

Comment: It should only come back after every major update (aka milestone updates) so far, windows 10 has only had 5 or so. All other updates won't bring it back. How did you uninstall it? Did you actually uninstalled it through remove apps?

Comment: What version of Win 10 are you running?

Comment: Beginning with 1703 metro apps that are Uninstalled normally (add/remove programs) are not reinstalled by default. I don't know how this works with One drive though, as that is becoming a more integrated part of Windows 10.

Comment: @LPChip I've uninstalled it from the old Add remove programs.

Comment: @music2myear Version 10.0.15063

Answer (score 1):

I had uninstalled OneDrive in 1703 (Creators Update) and have just now installed 1709 (Fall Creators Update) and OneDrive reappeared.

While most Metro apps are not being reinstalled by the major updates since the 1703 update, OneDrive is a more important component of Windows from Microsoft's perspective, and so it appears to be reintroducing it with each major update.